What is the right notion of transcendence degree for the fraction field of an affinoid algebra
Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra with fraction field $K$.
Then the Krull dimension of $A$ is equal to the transcendence degree of $K$ over $k$.
I would be very interested in any related result where $A$ is an affinoid algebra. I suppose then $K$ needs not be of finite transcendence degree. Is there any reasonable analogue of a finite transcendence basis that somehow takes the norm of $A$ into account?
Many thanks for answering!

The fact that you are using $K=\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ is misleading. The fraction field is only relevant because $K$ is the residue field of a point of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ — it is $k(\eta)$ for $\eta$ the generic point of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$.
So, perhaps a more true-to-geometry way to write your formula is the following. Suppose that $A$ is a finite type $k$-algebra. Then,
$$\displaystyle \dim(A)=\sup _{x\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)} \mathrm{tr.deg}(k(x)/k).$$
What this also highlights is also that you have to use $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and not $\mathrm{MaxSpec}(A)$ — you really need ‘non-classical points’ (i.e., not $\overline{k}$-points) to get the correct answer.
With these comments in mind, then a similar formula holds in rigid geometry. If $k$ is a non-archimedean field, and $A$ is an affinoid $k$-algebra (i.e., a topological $k$-algebra which is topologically of finite type), then
$$\dim(A)=\sup_{x\in\mathrm{Spa}(A)}\mathrm{trc.deg}(k(x)/k).$$
Let me explain the notation here:

$\mathrm{Spa}(A)=\mathrm{Spa}(A,A^\circ)$ is the adic space associated to $A$ — this shows up, and not something like the Tate spectrum $\mathrm{Sp}(A)$, for the same reason as before: you need to consider all, in particular non-classical, points to get the right formula,

$\mathrm{trc.deg}(k(x)/k)$ is a topological variant of transcendence degree, which is defined as the minimum of $\mathrm{tr.deg}(L/k)$ where $L$ runs over subextensions of $k(x)/k)$ which are ‘algebraically dense’ — you can obtain $L$ from $k$ by applying the operation $\widetilde{(-)}$ (i.e., the topological closure of the algebraic closure) finitely many times.


Remark: Because $k(x)=k(y)$ if $x$ and $y$ are related by specializations/generalizations, you can also replace $\mathrm{Spa}(A)$ by its Berkovich space $\mathcal{M}(A)$.

Hi Alex, thanks for the nice reply!
I am not very familiar with Huber spaces, so let us maybe stick to the Berkovich side. If I understand correctly, you associate to each residue field k(x) a transcendence degree that takes into account the topology coming from its nonarchimedian norm.
Would you kindly give me a reference for this statement?
I have a follow-up question: in The case where k(x) is the fraction field of the Tate algebra, can it ever happen that the generators $x_1,\dots, x_n$ do not form a transcendence basis of the kind you described?

@Kemal This follows from Lemma 1.8.6 part (ii) of Huber’s book on étale cohomology (your $S=\mathrm{Spa}(k,k^\circ)$ so it has only one, so minimal, point). Unfortunately I do not know the Berkovich literature as well, so I am not sure of a reference in that language (although I am sure it must exist). With respect to your last question: as I mentioned above, I don’t think the fraction field of the Tate algebra is really what you want to consider. Instead you’ll find that the appropriate $1$ comes from taking the ‘continuous transcendence degree’ of the residue field of the Gauss point.

Note that you can get the residue field at the Guass point by completing the fraction field of the Tate algebra, but I am not sure that is a helpful insight, and could be misleading in some sense.

@Kemal PS, if you are happy with my answer, you can upvote/accept it to clear it form the unanswered queue.

Many thanks Alex! I think your answer was exactly what I was looking for.
